# C# find text in a list that is in a tsv file

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to solve a task in a project on codeacademy, the task is to find a word in the tsv file which is made to a list with the following code:

```
List<Language> languages = File.ReadAllLines("./languages.tsv")
        .Skip(1)
        .Select(line => Language.FromTsv(line))
        .ToList();
```

I have tried the following and got error CS1929:

```
var ChiefDeveloperMS = languages.Where(chief => $"{chief.Contains("Microsoft")}");

foreach (var d in ChiefDeveloperMS)
        {
          Console.WriteLine($"{d.Prettify()}");
        }
```

The word i am looking for is Microsoft.

Prettify is a method in the language class with the following code:

```
public string Prettify()
    {
      return $"{Year}, {Name}, {ChiefDeveloper}, {Predecessors}";
    }
```

sample from the tsv file:

```
Year    Name    Chief developer, company    Predecessor(s)
1991    Visual Basic    Alan Cooper (sold to Microsoft) QuickBASIC
2001    GDScript(GDS)   OKAM Studio Godot
2001    Shakespeare Programming Language    Jon Åslund, Karl Hasselström    none
2002    Io  Steve Dekorte   Self,NewtonScript,Lua
2002    Gosu    Guidewire Software  GScript
2005    F#  Don Syme (Microsoft Research)   OCaml,C#,Haskell
```

Output that i got in the console:

```
1996, VBScript, Microsoft, Visual Basic
2001, Visual Basic .NET, Microsoft, Visual Basic
2006, Windows PowerShell, Microsoft, C#,ksh,Perl,CL,DCL,SQL
```

expected output:

```
1991    Visual Basic    Alan Cooper (sold to Microsoft) QuickBASIC
1996    VBScript    Microsoft   Visual Basic
2000    C#  Anders Hejlsberg (Microsoft, ECMA)  C,C++,Java,Delphi,Modula-2
2001    Visual Basic .NET   Microsoft   Visual Basic
2005    F#  Don Syme (Microsoft Research)   OCaml,C#,Haskell
2006    Windows PowerShell  Microsoft   C#,ksh,Perl,CL,DCL,SQL
```

I have tried many variations, searched all over and asked on the codeacademy facebook group and still cant find the answer, the correct namespaces are on top in progam.cs.

Yesterday i got help on stackoverflow with a workaround, it worked in a way but the problem is that it does not print the words that is in parentheses in the tsv file on the console.

Here is the workaround code:

```
var ChiefDeveloperMS = languages.Where(chief => chief.ChiefDeveloper == "Microsoft");
```

Constructor for the language class:

```
public Language(int year, string name, string chiefDeveloper, string predecessors)
    {
      Year = year;
      Name = name;
      ChiefDeveloper = chiefDeveloper;
      Predecessors = predecessors;
    }
```

What i dont understand is why the .Contain() method is not working when i have been using it successfully in a similar manner many times.

Should i just give this up and come back to this later? Is this to complicated for a beginner?

I am new here, if more information is required i will be happy to edit my post.

Comment: Not enough info to answer; give sample content of TSV, implementation of `Language.FromTsv` and be more specific about what word you're looking for, in what field, and what output result you want

Comment: `languages.Where(chief => chief.ChiefDeveloper == "Microsoft");` - don't name your linq lambdas like this. languages is a list of Language, the liqn operates on each element (which is a language) - write like `languages.Where(lang => lang.ChiefDeveloper == "Microsoft");` because it makes it more clear that the list item is a language, not a chief

Comment: I will try to provide more information, the tsv file is quite big, contains 120 lines @CaiusJard thanks for the tips in regards to how to name my linq

Comment: "sample content" like, 5 lines, one of which mentions "Microsoft"

Comment: @CaiusJard sample added

Comment: *does not print the words that is in parentheses in the tsv file* - only one of the words in the TSV file is wrapped in parentheses. Is that what you want? "GDS" ?

Comment: There word Microsoft is in 6 places in the file with chief developer 3 of them in parentheses and 3 that gets printed with the correct information. I need all 6 to be printed. Also codeacademy told me to use .Contains() method @CaiusJard yes you are correct that is what i want

Comment: Post a sample of the TSV that is RELEVANT to your question. You've posted 5 random lines, none of which contains "microsoft" and only one of which contains parentheses

Comment: @CaiusJard sample updated

Comment: Now give the expected output

Comment: Output and expected ouput updated @CaiusJard

Comment: Why does some of your expected output lines have a comma after the year and other lines do not?

Comment: @CaiusJard I made a and forgot to remove the commas when i copied it from the console, the ones without commas are copied from the tsv file istelf i will edit it to make it correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the reason why this:

```
var ChiefDeveloperMS = languages.Where(chief => $"{chief.Contains("Microsoft")}");
```

doesn't work is because it's all messed up

Where is a LINQ command that expects you to pass a function to it that returns a boolean (or an expression that evaluates to be a Boolean and

```
chief => $"{chief.Contains("Microsoft")}"
```

is not an expression that results in a Boolean. I'll pick it apart so you can know what went wrong

- `chief =>` gives a name to the list element that will be passed to the expression/function. You're calling Where on a list of Language objects so calling this `lang` would be better than chief. `chief` is (/`lang` would be) a Language object. If you want to get the ChiefDeveloper property of it you'd have to say `chief.ChiefDeveloper` -> can you see why I recommend to look at the collection of objects and pick a name that makes a good singular reference for an item in the collection? `lang.ChiefDeveloper` makes more sense than `chief.ChiefDeveloper` and helps you keep straight in your head what you're working with
- `$"` starts an interpolated string
- `{` within an interpolated string marks the start of a field that is evaluated
- `chief.Contains("Microsoft")` is a problem. Contains asks whether a string contains another string, but remember that your `chief` is a Language object, not a string. Language doesn't have a Contains method. If it did, it would return true or false, this would be incorporated into the string by the interpolation process and you'd end up with one of the following strings:

  "true"
  "false"

These are not booleans. They are strings that contain words that we commonly use when talking about booleans but they aren't booleans, "1234" is not a number or a time, and "04-09-2000" is not a date. These are all strings, regardless of what your brain might recognize and interpret when it sees them (oh, and 9th April or 4th Sep?)

Put all this together, name our collection properly, name our expression input variable well, make sure it returns a Boolean...

```
var msLangs = allLangs.Where(lang => lang.ChiefDeveloper.Contains("Microsoft"));
```

You can now iterate and print them:

```
    foreach (var msLang in msLangs)
    {
      Console.WriteLine(msLang.Prettify());
    }
```

Note I'm keeping the sensible naming - collections have plural names

- msLangs: a collection of Microsoft languages
- msLang: one of the above named collection items

You don't need to put msLang.Prettify inside an interpolated string. Prettify already returns a string. Wrapping it in an interpolated string that contains nothing else is a wasted operation

I also want to point out that prettify does not return a string in the format you say you want output. Prettify adds commas

Because it's probably fair to say your specification of the problem hasn't been as accurate as it could have been, I'm not sure whether to fix this last point or not. Either modify your prettify so it emits tabs rather than commas or bypass prettify and interpolate a string yourself.

Another (and final) point I want to raise is that software engineers work to specifications and the specs have to absolutely be accurate, complete, comprehensive etc. Hopefully this whole experience has been a worthwhile one for you because at the start your spec was awful; it couldn't at all be implemented - it was the half baked sort of thing your boss would drop on your desk and expect you to do, and if you did it and assumed etc you'd have ended up giving him something he didn't want. Always, when talking to other software devs, be meticulous about the accuracy of your specification and it's completeness. Always, when receiving a spec off someone, demand the same.. otherwise it will be "garbage in, garbage out"

Comment: Don't worry, we all need more practice! :)

Comment: Thank you for a really good and in depth answer. Clearly i need a lot more practice. it worked with 1 modification, i had to change the allLangs to languages. I cannot thank you enough, i will take your advice and try my best to implement it.

Comment: yes; i renamed languages to allLangs so that I could later draw a distinction with `msLangs` "microsoft languages" vs `allLangs`. Should have pointed that out, but you cracked it! ;) In a few years (or months even) read this question back; I'm sure you'll say "whoa, I don't even recognize the guy that wrote that Q". It's a nice way to reflect on the developer you were vs are!

Answer (score 0):

A tsv file is a TAB delimited file.  The data you posted does not have tabs.  The code below will work with a file that contains tabs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.txt";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            int row = 0;

            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(FILENAME);
            string line = "";
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {

                string[] data = line.Split(new char[] { '\t' });
                if (++row == 1)
                {
                    foreach (string name in data)
                    {
                        dt.Columns.Add(name, typeof(string));
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    dt.Rows.Add(data);
                }
            }


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I will try this, it is cool to learn a new way to do things. The only thing is that they ask to use .Contain() method specifically which means there is a way to do it with the mentioned method.